# Preimage of $T(x_1,x_2)= -\ln(x_2)\begin{pmatrix} \cos(2\pi x_1) \\ \sin(2\pi x_1)\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, trigonometry

Define $T(x_1,x_2)= -\ln(x_2)\begin{pmatrix} \cos(2\pi x_1) \\ \sin(2\pi x_1)\end{pmatrix} $.

Given a set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ which has the property that the norm $\| \cdot \|_2$ of any point in that set is between $m$ and $M$ for some positive numbers (so the set is a kind of like a flat torus) one bigger than the other, how can we find the inverse image of such a set?

Can I just say that the inverse mapping is given by $$t^{-1}(x_1,x_2) = \frac{-1}{\ln(x_2)}\begin{pmatrix} \arccos(x_1)/2\pi \\ \arcsin(x_1)/2\pi \end{pmatrix}$$
and then take this on my point in the torus? Is it well-defined, or do we need further assumptions?